# Can I get find to switch to next root directory when finding a match?

Tags: bash, find

The `find` program has a `-quit` cmdline option, which tells it to quit immediately after finding a match and executing previously-specificed commands (like `-print`). That's very useful, but what if I'm `find`'ing within several root directories, and want the first match in every one of the roots?

Is there a way of saying something like:

```
find foo bar baz -print -continue-with-next-root
```

? Some shell code is ok, but I would like to avoid a separate `find` invocation for each root folder.

Comment: I suspect this isn’t what you’re after, but `find foo bar baz -print -prune` would meet the apparent requirements for your example. It doesn’t work if the tests you’re really interested in involve actually descending inside each directory... (In other words, an example closer to what you really want would ensure you get useful answers.)

Comment: "I would like to avoid a separate `find` invocation for each root folder" – Why? IMO the simplicity of this solution is its big advantage. What can we win or substantially improve by inventing an alternative?

Comment: Prune is close probably, but it stops descending the current hierarchy, and  parent directories in the same root would not be pruned.  I don't see a way to do this without -quit and a shell loop, and the performance would be the same.  i don't see any downsides to using a shell loop.

Comment: If you are using `find` a lot, you might find using `locate` to build a database of pathnames an optimal alternative.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: I was thinking that, for a large list of root folders, it's more appropriate to avoid a hundred or a thousand invocations of a process.

Comment: @meuh: That would make an answer, actually. Although the contents of those directories might change.

Comment: @einpoklum if you explain what the find command is actually doing, we can give alternatives. The `locate` command is great, but it isn't a replacement for find and depending on what you want, it might be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bite the bullet and use a separate `find` invocation for each root folder. The overhead is negligible, and there is no such `find` option anyway, so you might as well:

```
for dir in dir1 dir2 dir2 ... dirN; do
   find ... -quit
done
```

I really don't think you will find a better solution.

Comment: 1. Why the `...` after `find`? 2. How negligible?

Comment: @einpoklum the `…` is a placeholder (meaning: fill in your options here as used before). A better example can't be given, because you didn't specify any specific find criteria!

Comment: @einpoklum why don't *you* benchmark the overhead? We can't tell you what the limiting factors in spawning processes on your computer are! Generally, when someone says "negligible" it means: can't imagine a case where you can negatively notice the difference; it's not *that* ambigous a term, even if it's not a *precise* term. But you're a also not asking a question precise enough to quantify overhead: You're not even telling us what your find criteria actually are, how many files how deep in folders you're searching through, how many starting directories you are considering.

Comment: @einpoklum And depending on how often you do the task, [the optimization you seek may or may not be worth the hassle](https://xkcd.com/1205/). Even after finding a faster way, *applying* it may be uneconomic ([example](https://superuser.com/q/937586/432690)).

Comment: @einpoklum what the others said. I honestly cannot imagine a situation where launching multiple find commands will be noticeably slower given that the main thing is searching the directories.